# Dynamically building an expression tree for an EF Where() clause

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, reflection, expression-trees

I want to build a custom `Where` expression that I can pass to the `Where` clause of an Entity Framework query.

Below is as far as I've got.

```
// ???

ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(StorageDetail), "d");

if (HasRailcarNumber.HasValue)
{
    Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(StorageDetail).GetProperty("RailcarNumber"));
    Expression right = Expression.Constant(null);
    Expression e2 = (HasRailcarNumber.Value == true) ?
        Expression.Equal(left, right) :
        Expression.NotEqual(left, right);

    // What to do with e2 ???

}

if (IsTakeOrPay.HasValue)
{
    Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(StorageDetail).GetProperty("TakeOrPayStartDate"));
    Expression right = Expression.Constant(null);
    Expression e2 = (HasRailcarNumber.Value == true) ?
        Expression.Equal(left, right) :
        Expression.NotEqual(left, right);

    // What to do with e2 ???

}

if (HasArrived.HasValue)
{
    Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(StorageDetail).GetProperty("ArrivalDate"));
    Expression right = Expression.Constant(null);
    Expression e2 = (HasRailcarNumber.Value == true) ?
        Expression.Equal(left, right) :
        Expression.NotEqual(left, right);

    // What to do with e2 ???

}
```

My first question is how do I start the body? I don't want my expresion to call `Where()`. I want `Where` to call my expression.

Second question is once I have my subexpressions (`e2` above), how do I combine them? (Using `AndAlso`.) Note that it's possible that all three properties are `null`, in which case the expression should not filter anything (should be a null expression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've assumed you should use [`Expression.AndAlso`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.andalso?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_AndAlso_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_) for `AND` logic. If it is the case, you can create "start" expression evaluating to `true` and add others to it:

```
Expression expr = Expression.Constant(true);
if (HasRailcarNumber.HasValue)
{
    ...
    expr = Expression.AndAlso(expr, e2);
}
if (IsTakeOrPay.HasValue)
{
    ...
    expr = Expression.AndAlso(expr, e2);
}
if (HasArrived.HasValue)
{
    ...
    expr = Expression.AndAlso(expr, e2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I convert that `Expression` to a `Where()` condition (`Expression<Func<StorageDetail, bool>>`)?

Comment: You should use `Expression.Lambda`. Something like that: `Expression.Lambda<Func<StorageDetail, bool>>(expr, pe)`